# Multiline Textbox Vertical Spacing (Winform)

Tags: winforms, textbox, spacing

I am using the standard textbox control on a Windows form.  I want to display the text VERTICALLY rather than horizontally.  To accomplish this I set the multiline property to true, the TextAligh property to center and used the lines property to input each character as a separate array element.  So far, so good.

I see the text displayed the way I want but would like to reduce the vertical spacing between lines without reducing the font size.  Can it be done?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, but not by the default options on a standard textbox.

You would probably need to override the Paint event and draw the text yourself, but it would get very ugly, and would essentially be reinventing the standard Paint method.